# Not able to apply custom css applied for rich:dataTable header class

Tags: jsf-2, richfaces

I am working on sample project of JSF 2.0 with richfaces 4.Probelm is richfaces skin are not applied to the components.

i want to use custom css for HeaderClass of Richdatatable but i am not able to show that. only inbuilt css are applied to headers. even for  columnClasses also if i used only single value like this :  columnClasses="JspContentForDataTable , its not showing i have to do columnClasses="JspContentForDataTable,JspContentForDataTable,JspContentForDataTable,JspContentForDataTable" for each column.

web.xml :

```
    <context-param>
        <param-name>org.richfaces.skin</param-name>
        <param-value>ruby</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>org.ajax4jsf.VIEW_HANDLERS</param-name>
        <param-value>com.sun.facelets.FaceletViewHandler</param-value>
    </context-param>


    <context-param>
        <param-name>org.richfaces.CONTROL_SKINNING</param-name>
        <param-value>disable</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <context-param>
     <param-name>org.richfaces.LoadStyleStrategy</param-name>
     <param-value>None</param-value>
</context-param>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>org.jboss.jbossfaces.WAR_BUNDLES_JSF_IMPL</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>
```

Please correct if i am doing anything wrong.
Help me out thanks in advanced.

Comment: What pops to mind is that you could use css. Use Firebug to find the correct classes to set in CSS, possibly with !important to override the default styles.

Comment: thanks for reply. i have checked that in firebug it shows only built in css class is applied to the header <th>. add when i add manually customclass then style chagens. but dont know why programmitically it is not applying.

Answer (score 0):

The main reason why your styles are not getting applied to the element/component is that the style sheets are loaded earlier and then over-written by the default styles, to include the styles at run-time you have to import your style-sheets using  tag

Eg:-

`<h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="style.css"  />`

Remember to include the declaration in the <**h:head>** tag of your page.
For more detailed descriptions on loading a css at run-time using  refer this link

[Including css using h:outputStyleet](http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/how-to-include-cascading-style-sheets-css-in-jsf/)

Okay I think I found your fix try this, there seems to be some problem while applying the css to your custom datatable.

Include this statement in your base file or current page.

For any custom component you add include the basic rich tag you include in that component that's causing you some issue as an non rendered component and it would work out just fine.

Eg:- For your current custom tag the basic rich component you might be using is an rich:dataTable right so add this component with a **rendered="false**" in your file where you use the component.

Like  <**rich:dataTable rendered="false"/>** this would fix your issue fingers crossed not certain about why this happens but this should fix the issue.

Comment: Your welcome :)
Ideally this is the one that would work out in most of the scenarios don't know why you still seem to be facing the issue...